# Why is audio stream playback faster in Firefox than in Chrome?

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

The example below plays almost instantly if I click on play as soon as possible when page is loaded, in Firefox. But in Chrome the playback will take about 4 seconds before playing sound. Why is it so and what can I do to speed this up in Chrome?

The audio source is an mp3 stream streaming from an Icecast server.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="audio" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="http://..." controls />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you update the chrome?

Comment: Upload a packet capture, so we can see what's going on.  Chances are, you have a pretty low buffer size set on your server.  (See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504992/google-cast-slow-for-some-streams/52507935#52507935)